# Optimal Combat Load out Based off Certain Weapons

Tags: kenshi

What would be the most optimal choices as a load out for a character that's based off a Katana? My current load out is;

- Head - Armored Face Plates
- Armor - Plate Jacket
- Shirt - Leather Turtleneck
- Pants - Armored Rag Skirt
- Boots - Plated Long boots

Everything is at least Spec Grade or Higher. Dont really know if theres something better to what I currently use , Weight isnt really a issue when most of my Pawns have 20+ Strength, but would still like to have them light in case I have to move around the map.

Comment: It depends on offence verus defence really. Lots of armor will not only mean slower running spead, but also reduced chances to hit. But obviously you can take a beating far better. Reading the details of each armor piece is usually enough. I don't remember all the details but there's definitely better kinds than what you have listed here, these are standard parts. The various samurai and ninja parts for example. Bit harder to come by but overall better stats iirc.

Comment: If you are tanking, a holy armor chest piece from some of the Holy Nation traders is even heavier than your plate jacket. Note that as long as your strength is high enough for the (weight) armor you are carrying, in general only boots and pants have movement (athletic) penalties; head and chest armor may slow you due to weight but don't have actual movement penalties. Also note that pants with 100% leg coverage also covers your feet, so wear sandals for the +2 movement they give you. Or just swap in plate shoes when tanking and sandals when traveling.